# How to use an iterator within an ES6 class method

Tags: javascript, iterator, ecmascript-6, es6-class

I'm experimenting with iterators within ES6 classes and am running into a reference error: `ReferenceError: vertex is not defined` when creating an each method for my class. I'm able to add my vertexes to the graph and the graph instance prints with the correct data. Is the use of this iterator correct?

```
class Vertex {
  constructor(key) {
    this.id = key
    this.connectedTo = {}
  }
}

class Graph {
  constructor() {
    this.vertexList = {}
    this.numVerticies = 0
  }

[Symbol.iterator]() {
     // Reflect.ownKeys() === Object.keys()
  const vertexListKeys = Reflect.ownKeys(this.vertexList)
  let index = 0
  return {
    next: () => {
         // Reflect.get(myObj, key) === Object[key]
      let value = Reflect.get(this.vertexList, vertexListKeys[index])
      index++
      return {
        done: index > vertexListKeys.length ? true : false,
        value: value
        }
      }
    }
  }

// Iterate through vertexList values
 each(callback) {
  for (vertex of this) {
    callback(vertex)
    }
  }

 addVertex(key) {
   const newVertex = new Vertex(key)
     this.vertexList[key] = newVertex
     this.numVerticies++
   return newVertex
  }


}



const graph = new Graph()

for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
  g.addVertex(i)
}


graph.each((vert) => console.log(vert))
// ReferenceError: vertex is not defined
// for (vertex of this) {
//               ^
```

I have also tried changing my each method to a generator, however nothing prints to the console when I do so

```
*each(callback) {
  for(vertex in this) {
    yield callback(vertex) // omitting yield doesn't work either
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is just what it says

```
for (vertex of this) {
```

uses a variable `vertex` that isn't declared anywhere. It should be

```
for (var vertex of this) {
```

or `let` or `const`.

Answer (score 0):

```
    class Vertex {
  constructor(key) {
    this.id = key
    this.connectedTo = {}
  }
}

class Graph {
  constructor() {
    this.vertexList = {}
    this.numVerticies = 0
  }

[Symbol.iterator]() {
     // Reflect.ownKeys() === Object.keys()
  const vertexListKeys = Reflect.ownKeys(this.vertexList)
  let index = 0
  return {
    next: () => {
         // Reflect.get(myObj, key) === Object[key]
      let value = Reflect.get(this.vertexList, vertexListKeys[index])
      index++
      return {
        done: index > vertexListKeys.length ? true : false,
        value: value
        }
      }
    }
  }

// Iterate through vertexList values
 each(callback) {
  for (var vertex of this) {
    callback(vertex)
    }
  }

 addVertex(key) {
   const newVertex = new Vertex(key)
     this.vertexList[key] = newVertex
     this.numVerticies++
   return newVertex
  }


}



const g = new Graph()

for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
  g.addVertex(i)
}


g.each((vert) => console.log(vert))
```

In the each function it should be `var vertex` because  `vertex` is not declared yet .